# Most efficient way to get process resource utilisation info without reparsing text

Tags: linux, performance, process, monitoring, system-calls

What's the most efficient way in Linux to get resource utilization data of processes?

- `procfs` seems to require reparsing text each time.
- `getrusage` seems to be only for the calling process.

While `procfs` seems to be efficient otherwise, it does require parsing text and converting them to integers which is wasteful.

Is is there a system call or something that I'm missing on Linux that can be used to get the raw data from the kernel process tables?

For example, Windows has the `PSAPI` that almost every program in the ecosystem uses, with efficient APIs like `OpenProcess`, `GetProcessIoCounters`, `GetProcessTimes` etc.